# Perl regex, insert value between commas

Tags: regex, perl

I have a CSV file, and some of the fields are empty.

Sample Data

```
ItemA,5,4,3,2,1
ItemB,7,,,2,4
ItemC,,,,2,
ItemD,,3,,,
```

I'd like to pass a perl one liner over the file, that would insert a string, say NULL in between each comma, or after the final comma if no value exists after it.

so after regex, data should look like:

```
ItemA,5,4,3,2,1
ItemB,7,NULL,NULL,2,4
ItemC,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,NULL
ItemD,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

I don't know how to create this regex, assistance is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, use positive lookbehind and lookahead assertions like below.

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=,)(?=,|$)/NULL/g' file
ItemA,5,4,3,2,1
ItemB,7,NULL,NULL,2,4
ItemC,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,NULL
ItemD,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

- `(?<=,)` Just lookafter to all the commas. That is, it asserts that the match must be preceded by a comma.
- `(?=,|$)` And the match was immediately followed by a comma or end of the line anchor. So it matches all the boundaries which exists inbetween all the commas and the one which are next to the comma which are at the last.
- Replacing the matched boundary with `NULL` string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use regex. Use a core module `Text::ParseWords`:

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -lne'
    @w = parse_line (",", 1, $_);
    print join ",", map { (length) ? $_ : "NULL" } @w
' file
ItemA,5,4,3,2,1
ItemB,7,NULL,NULL,2,4
ItemC,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,NULL
ItemD,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

or alternatively use the optional third param for `split`.

```
perl -lne'
    @F = split ",", $_, -1; 
    print join ",", map { (length) ? $_ : "NULL" } @F
' file
ItemA,5,4,3,2,1
ItemB,7,NULL,NULL,2,4
ItemC,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,NULL
ItemD,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: OP asked for a regex perl oneliner, you say you wouldn't use a regex, any reason not to?

Comment: @outlyer It's just my personal opinion. Parsing a csv file using regex is never a good choice to begin with. The solution might be short but may break at odd use cases.

Comment: Agreed, regexes aren't a good choice in general for CSV, although your alternate solution with `split` will also fail in some use cases. `Text::ParseWords` seems a lot more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution with a regex:

```
$ perl -pe 's/,(?=,)|,$/,NULL/g' file.csv

ItemA,5,4,3,2,1
ItemB,7,NULL,NULL,2,4
ItemC,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,NULL
ItemD,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

I.e. match a comma immediately followed by a comma (`,(?=,)`) OR a comma at the end of the line (`,$`), and replace the matched comma with `,NULL`.

---

EDIT: As pointed out by *Casimir et Hippolyte*, `s/,(?=,|$)/,NULL/g` is simpler.

(Match a comma immediately followed by another comma or by the line's end).

Comment: put your alternation in the lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fpath = "./data.txt";

open(my $fh, '<', $fpath) or die "*** Cannot open $fpath:\n$!\n";

while ( <$fh> ) {
    while(1) { last if ( $_ !~ s/,\s*,/,NULL,/g ) }
    $_ =~ s/,\s*$/,NULL/g;
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I tested and this didn't work, it replaced some but not all of the instances.  Why is there a \s* in the regex?

Comment: The file `./data.txt` is your CSV file.